# Versioning with Oracle Workspace Manager in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, oracle-dbms, versioning

I'm working with a workspace enabled oracle database. Through the database connection properties in QGIS meanwhile it is possible to set the workspace or version. So I can edit my spatial data in a given version.

Is it also possible to write a new workspace/version with QGIS?

I want to edit my spatial data and save them into a new workspce/version of my oracle database.